# Structure data like map <key,<value>> in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, key-value

I need a sort of data structure like Hashmap but I need to associate a list of values to one key: >

Is there already a predefined structure  on Java? or should I  implement it?

Comment: Map<Key, List<Something>>?

Comment: You can use a list as the value type.

Comment: Not predefined, but who cares: https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37987668/structure-data-like-map-key-value-in-java?noredirect=1#comment63419628_37987668) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed use a `Map<Key, List<Value>>` but you have also [Multimap](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) in Google Guava that could be interesting too in your case with several implementations like [ArrayListMultimap](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html).

Answer (score 2):

JDK 1.7 already contains a [MultiValuedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html) having a signature like `public interface MultivaluedMap<K,V> extends Map<K,List<V>>`. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Actually IN java there is no built-in collection for this type, but you can declare like `Map<Key, List<YourClass>>.`

Even you can use Google's [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) collection library, where You can use `MultiMaps`.
See this link for how to use it: https://dzone.com/articles/multimaps-google-guava

Answer (score 0):

You can create the POJO class of your needs and can create the HashMap like:
(I take key in String, POJO class Car)

```
    Map<String, List<Car>> carDetails = new HashMap<String, List<Car>>();

class Car{
    private String headLight;

    public void setHeadLine(String headLight){
          this.headLight = headLight;
     }

    public String getHeadLight(){
           return headLight;
     }
    }
```

This makes a structure like table in the database with the primary key.
Hope this helps...!!!